# Why do I need +-1 in a Binary Search?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, search, binary-search

So I'm curious.. Why is it that I need to do `+1` and `-1` when truncating a side of the array.
I get that an array is index based and starts at 0 but is that really the reason to why I need to do it? What's the actual logic behind it? I've noticed that if I don't do it, it just never exists the loop because it gets to a point where it just keeps dividing the values to the same value over and over again.

```
private static int[] values = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 13, 15, 17 };
public static int FindValue(int valueToFind)
{
    int l = 0;
    int r = values.Length - 1;
    while (l <= r)
    {
        var mid = (l + r) / 2;
        if (values[mid] == valueToFind)
            return mid;
        if (values[mid] < valueToFind)
            l = mid + 1;
        else
            r = mid - 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify why "I've noticed that if I don't do it, it just never exists the loop because it gets to a point where it just keeps dividing the values to the same value over and over again." is not the reason you are looking for?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it does work without the `+1` and `-1`.

Comment: if you try that exact snippet I sent, it won't work. It'll get stuck in an infinite loop (if you add 20 as the parameter) and remove +-1 :/

Comment: Fair enough, it doesn't work for elements that aren't in the array. It does work without the `-1` though.

Comment: Yeah, that I noticed while debugging actually. What I'm currently trying to figure out is.. Given the same test scenario we just discussed (if the number is not in the array and +-1 doesn't exist) why it's not making any progress once it reaches a certain point.

Comment: Do you know what the value of the expression `1/2` is?

Comment: .5 but in C# it rounds down to the closest integer, so 0?

Comment: It doesn't round down, it truncates, but that's basically the idea. Now apply that to the expression `(n+(n+1))/2` and look back at the code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If instead of `l = mid + 1;` we would have `l = mid;` then a problem arises when the `l` and `r` differ by at most 1 (so there are at most two array values in the running). In that case `(l + r) / 2 == l`, so that `mid` will be equal to `l`. Now let's suppose the value we look for is greater than `values[mid]`, then the `if` block will execute and `l` will be assigned `mid`. But it already *had* that value, so nothing changes! The next iteration will start with exactly the same state as the previous one, and we'll loop without end.

If you would replace `r = mid - 1;` with just `r = mid`, then a similar problem can arise when there is just one value in the array left, i.e. `l` and `r` are equal. If the value we look for is less than that only value `values[mid]`, then `r` will be assigned `mid`, but again, it already had that value. Nothing changes, and the looping goes on for ever.

The reasoning to have the +1 and -1 in those assignments is that:

- it ensures that the interval will get smaller in each iteration, and so it will be impossible to have an infinite loop
- it excludes `mid` from the reduced range, which makes sense, as with the first `if` we already compared with the value at that index, so it is no longer a candidate.

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean, that makes so much sense! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

taking in your last comment, I would assume that it's a rounding issue. It's rounding up and the next calculated number is still higher than the target value. I would add some console logging to printout the value as it's searching.